# How to Add Facebook Audience Network Native Ads In Between RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, facebook-audience-network

I am a beginner at the android studio I have created a recycler view which parses JSON and display in recycler view. I searched the whole internet.,but I could not find a tutorial to place Facebook ads in between recycler view please help me.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need [This](https://github.com/ldt116/FBNativeAdAdapter) to add facebook native ad in between RecycleView